# How do I update the firmware on my Sony eBook Reader?

Tags: updates, hardware, ebooks

I've a Sony Ebook Reader PRS-T1. I have Calibri and there is no problem to put ebooks on the Reader, but I don't know how to update the firmware. Perhaps you can help me?

Regrets 
Malte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the firmware, you can:

1. Get an access to a windows machine, and do the update that way.
2. Install Windows in a Virtual Machine under Ubuntu.
3. Follow the steps mentioned [Here](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/PRST1_Firmware_Upgrade)

> > The page above give step-by-step instructions for installing firmware
> >     to the Sony PRS-T1 eReader.
> >
> > 1. Fully charge your PRS-T1
> > 2. Connect your PRS-T1 to your PC. Start the Reader software if it doesn't auto-start.
> > 3. Check for Updates, and follow the GUI prompts.

Then

> 1. Fully charge your PRS-T1
> 2. Download the stand-alone firmware updater file from Sony's support site.
> 3. Extract the file by right click, and choose "Extract here"
> 4. Connect your PRS-T1 to your PC with the USB cable (causing it to mount its 'SETTING' and 'READER' partitions).
> 5. Go to the location where you extracted the file.
> 6. Copy the PRS-T1 Updater.package files to the 'READER' file system.( /media/READER/ )
> 7. Disconnect the PRS-T1 from the USB cable.
> 8. Power down the PRS-T1 (a full power off to the blank screen).
> 9. Hold down both the home button and the menu button, and, while keeping them held, press the power button to turn on the PRS-T1.
> 10. Release the home and menu buttons once the boot screen is shown.
>
> The PRS-T1 should now install the update and automatically reboot once
>   done.

For other info you can [check this out](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/PRST1_Rooting_and_Tweaks#Firmware_Upgrade_via_Linux)

<sup>Source: [http://wiki.mobileread.com](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/PRST1_Firmware_Upgrade)</sup>

Comment: This is a little misleading/confusing, really only the part after "Then" is the answer.